# I have a range of values in cell F1 to G10 . I need to look up for these range in another range of value in cell B1 to C10

Tags: excel

I have a range of values in cell `F1` to `G10` (e.g. `10 - 20, 30-50,...`). I need to look up for these range in another range of value in cell `B1` to `C10` (e.g `1 - 100, 150- 200, 1-50, 20-60,...`).

While looking for the range, I need that the result should be highlighted in the next cell.

Comment: What is in F1? What is in G1? What is in F2? What is in G2? etc. Your question is not clear. Post a link to a sample file (use a file sharing service).  Mock up the desired results manually. Explain the logic. Use words. Lots of words.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/CNP6u.jpg

Comment: I have a range of values in cell F2 to G4. I need to look up for these range in another range of value in cell B2 to C4. While looking for the range, I need that the result should be highlighted in the next cell. Kindly help me to solve my problem. I need to get the cell value of A2, A3,A4 as the desired result for my query F2:G2 in the H2 cell.Query F2:G2 i.e 200 - 300 values lie in the range of B2:C2, B3:C3 and B4:C4. I need all the three values as a result in H2. Image is in the previous comment.

Comment: @JyotikaBhati it's not clear how one range relates to the other. Is row 2 of range 1 want to 'lookup' row 2 of range 2?  Can you add an image of the desired output(what it should look like)

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/CNP6u.jpg

Comment: You probably should use Conditional Formatting feature in Excel worksheets. Otherwise, switch to a VBA solution. Kind regards,